# Get list of users when it is midnight in their timezone

Tags: django

I need to send an email to my users when it is midnight in their timezone. I think my approach is fine, but I am having an issue with the Django F() function in my query.

Here is the query:

```
target_offset = 0 - timezone.now().hour

        users_to_email = User.objects.exclude(
            timezone__isnull=True
        ).annotate(
            tz_offset=Value(
                int (datetime.now(F('timezone')).strftime('%z')) / 100,
                models.IntegerField()
            )
        ).filter(
            tz_offset=target_offset
        )
```

I get this error:

```
    int (datetime.now(F('timezone')).strftime('%z')) / 100,
  File "/Users/leeloftiss/Desktop/daisy_coder/website/djangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/freezegun/api.py", line 386, in now
    result = tz.fromutc(now.replace(tzinfo=tz)) + cls._tz_offset()
AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'fromutc'
```

If I just call F('timezone') outside of the datetime.now() function, I get the actual value from the users TIMEZONE column.

So I guess I just need to know how I can get that value in this case where I need it in the datetime.now() function.

Note: I am using SQL, not Postgres

Comment: How is the user's timezone stored and in what format? Can you provide the model

Comment: It is the PYTZ string stored as a CharField. ex; 'US/Pacific'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will filter at the database side, so using `datetime.now(F('timezone'))` will not work. What you can do is "prepare" the list of timezones with a given offset:

```
from pytz import all_timezones, timezone
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

now = datetime.utcnow()
day = timedelta(days=1)
target_offset = timedelta(hours=now.hour) % day

timezones = {
    tz
    for tz in all_timezones
    if timezone(tz).utcoffset(now) % day == target_offset
}
```

This will generate a set `timezones` that contains the names of all timezones with the given offset. Next we can filter the users for that timezone:

```
users_to_email = User.objects.filter(
    timezone__in=timezones
)
```